# Not Interactable dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to select any one of the element from the list displaying when click is made on the particular dropdown selection box, but after the elements got listed, I could not select any element from the list.
I also tried with many familiar options.

```
WebElement autocompleteDropdown = driver.findElement(autocompleteSuggestions);
java.util.List<WebElement> suggestionList = autocompleteDropdown.findElements(By.xpath("//span//ul[@id='select2-unit_type_id-results']"));
System.out.println("suggestion list taken");               
    for (WebElement element : suggestionList) {         
        if (element.getText().equals("1 Bedroom Townhouse")) {
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
           Actions act1 =  new Actions(driver);
           act1.click().moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
           break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the URL of the website if it's public?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please add enough code to allow us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thank you guys for all your reply and effort , i sorted this by myslef ...